# I get the following error Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'string' password == "55555" is marked as an error

Tags: operator-keyword

```
namespace if4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string username;
            int password = new int();

            string userValue;
            userValue = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter your username:");
            userValue = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your password: ");
            if (username == "code" && password == "55555")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Access allowed! ");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Access denied! ");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What language is this? C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't compare int with string, you need to declare password as string, not int, or convert "55555" to int, or `password == 555555`